# Projectile motion question involving a bullet

Tags: projectile-motion

I have the question

> A bullet is fired horizontally at a speed of $65$ m/s from the top of a vertical cliff overlooking the sea. The height of the cliff is $10$ m.
>
> Calculate:
>
> a) The time for which the bullet is in the air before it enters the sea.
>
> b) The speed and angle to the horizontal of the bullet when it enters the sea."

Here is my attempt:

[image]

[image]

Are these correct ? If not could you point out what I have done wrong?

Comment: Looks like you were doing fine until you got to the angle calculation.

Comment: I am not sure how to find the angle to the horizontal any tips ? Thanks :)

Comment: You started off correctly with $\theta = \tan^{-1}(v_y/v_x)$ but then seem to have gotten confused. Just plug in the values that you’ve already computed.

Comment: But does this not give a negative angle ? Can you have negative angles ? Thanks :)

Comment: What’s wrong with that? You can interpret the negative sign to mean that it’s below the horizontal.

Comment: Okay thanks I understand now :)